# VS Code, OmniSharp: Project has these unresolved references:

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying out Asp.Net Core and MVC 6 running on Mac OS X. After I've updated and installed everything it seems to be working pretty good. I can run a website with 'dnx web' that's been generated by Yeoman.

OmniSharp starts correctly but displays this message,

**[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Dnx.DnxProjectSystem] Project /Users/myname/AspNetCoreProjects/test1/project.json has these unresolved references: Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics, Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers, Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel, Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles, Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug**

I've tried to run 'dnu restore' several times. And it seems to succeed. It writes a lock file and so on. But for some reason OmniSharp / VS Code doesn't seem to find any references (except my own classes) at all.

It feels like I'm having the same problem described here,
http://tech.genericwhite.com/visual-studio-2015-net-5-rc1-dnu-restore-asp-dot-net-missing

But that didn't work for me.

Any idea is very helpful!

Comment: same here... did you find a solution by any chance?

Comment: Nope, still having the same problem. :/

Comment: for me it was the incorrect dnu version along with no exec permissions. Would you post the result of the commands: `dnx --version`, `dnu --version` and `ls -l ~/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-{your_coreclr_version}/bin | grep dn`. Also post your `"frameworks":` section on your project.json file, I think I might be able to help you. EDIT: Also post the output of: `dnvm list`. :)

Comment: @eestein Here you have the output,

https://gist.github.com/Nordis/dc9e2a0cb6f129928ca87f03c4617653

Comment: Ok, you're not using core, right? Is that your goal? In any case, there's still one more command I'd need you to run, please check my comment above, the `ls -l ...`, also show me on your project.json the frameworks section. Cheers!

Comment: Ah, sorry. Regarding the folder it seems to be missing. If I go to ~/.dnx/runtimes/ it's empty. No hidden files / directories. Regarding the output of project.json you can see it here: https://gist.github.com/Nordis/ec23adba638610bff121d573b894e08f

Comment: @eestein Thanks for all your help!

Comment: No problem. If your runtimes folder is empty something's wrong. I'm going to post an answer to help you install the runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, install the runtime:

```
//to install coreclr
dnvm install latest -r coreclr -a coreclr-latest
//to install the clr
dnvm install latest -a mono-latest    

dnvm alias default [coreclr-latest | mono-latest] //depends on what you installed
dnvm use default
```

Let me know the output of `ls -l ~/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-{your_coreclr_version}/bin | grep dn` once you've ran those commands.

This is what your runtimes folder should look like:

[image]

I'm also writing a 5 five part tutorial on how to use `ASP.NET Core` along with with `JSPM`, `TypeScript`, etc as the frontend. If you don't care much for that you can take a look at the backend part (part 3) here:

http://ahoycoders.com/2016/03/29/jspm-with-systemjs-es6-angularjs-typescript-and-asp-net-core-part-3-backend/

This part focuses on installing and running `ASP.NET Core` on MacOS.

Let me know how it goes :)

**EDIT:** One thing I forgot to mention, before running `dnu restore` again remove `"dnx451": {},` from your `project.json`

**EDIT2:** Make sure you install the `coreclr` option. From your post it seems you want to use `ASP.NET Core`

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

I guess the problem was that the runtimes folder was empty for some reason. Now everything seems to be working. :-)